# QuerySyntaxException occurred for JPA @Query for Distinct and Count

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, microservices

I am using the below as a JpaRepository interface method query

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT order.status, COUNT(*) FROM OrderEntity order WHERE order.customerNumber = ?1 GROUP BY order.status")
```

During app startup I am getting the following exception -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: order near line 1, column 17 [SELECT DISTINCT order.status AS status, COUNT(*) AS count FROM debomitra.cmw.orders.entity.OrderEntity order WHERE order.customerNumber = ?1 GROUP BY order.status]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:600)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:709)
    ... 116 more
```

Is there any other way to write DISTINCT/COUNT query in JPA or am I doing something wrong? 
Please provide me with some pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the order keyword in the JPQL. It is expecting a "by" keyword after the "order".

Whoever is reading this try avoiding "order" keyword in a statement expect at the end where you really need to issue a ORDER BY statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query will work if you modify it like below-

```
SELECT DISTINCT OrderEntity.status, COUNT(*) FROM OrderEntity WHERE OrderEntity.customerNumber = ?1 GROUP BY OrderEntity.status
```